# How to change meta tags in a joomla site?

Tags: facebook, joomla, youtube

I want to change `og` code from my joomla site. Meta tag is showing

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://119.18.55.52/~videosco/images/video_thumb/funnycat_thumb.jpg" />
```

This is not a video thumbnail. It is a simple image, that i provide in a article.
I'm using `ja_fubix` template. When I click on `share button` only that image is shown which i added in my article.

Please help me out to show a video thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$shareTitle.'" />'  );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$shareDesc.'" />' );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$shareImg.'" />' );
```

For more [read](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-set-meta-data-of-a-page-in-joomla).

Hope its helps..

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is not working. As i'm using ja_fubix template so there is predefined meta tags. with this code it is not changing.

Comment: use $doc->setMetaData('og:image', "your image"); it will add on top while sharing this one will share. You can't change once its added to the page.

Comment: i have many videos.. then how it is possible to add them separately.

Comment: video is showing in a component view right ? like article or any custom component go to that component layout add the above code with dynamic urls(that will get from layout).If its article the edit should be template override otherwise Joomla updation will remove your core edits.

Comment: This will not set the meta tag it will add meta tags.